# b-pagination not displaying correctly, showing all elements on each page

Tags: javascript, vue.js, pagination, bootstrap-vue

I'm using BootstrapVue 3 to make a component with a b-table. I used b-pagination to try and paginate the table but it isn't displaying correctly.

I have it set to display 2 objects per page but instead it displays all objects on every page, while adding a page for every 2 objects.

Here is the template for my b-table:

```
 <template>
  <b-container fluid="xl">
    <div class="api-list">
        <h2>API Listing</h2> 

        <b-pagination
          v-model="currentPage"
          :total-rows="rows"
          :per-page="perPage"
          aria-controls="my-table"
        ></b-pagination>
        
        <p class="mt-3">Current Page: {{ currentPage }}</p>

        <b-table
          id="my-table"
          striped hover :items="items"
          :per-page="perPage"
          :current-page="currentPage"
          small
        ></b-table>
      </div>
  </b-container>
</template>
```

And here is my script:

```
<script>
import axios from "axios"
export default {
    data() {
      return {
        perPage: 2,
        currentPage: 1,
        items: [],
      }
    },
    computed: {
      rows() {
          return this.items.length
      }
    },
    async mounted() {
    try {
                const url = "http://localhost:3030/get-api-list";
                await axios.get(url, {
                }).then((res) => {
                    if (res.data.length < 1) {
            console.log("none found");
                    } else {
            this.items = res.data;
                    }
                });
            } catch (e) {
                console.error(e);
            }
    console.log(this.items);
  },
}
</script>
```

Note this component is imported into another component before viewing.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code and everything was good. I provided a code snippet here for you to see what is wrong on your side. Please make sure that the versions of your libraries are correct. I'm not sure which version of bootstrap-vue you are using, so let me know if you are using another version and I will try to reproduce your problem.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      perPage: 2,
      currentPage: 1,
      items: [],
    }
  },
  methods: {
    get_items() {
      // This method calls your API service and change items variable with the returend response.
      this.items = [{
          name: "Book 1",
          price: 200,
        },
        {
          name: "Book 2",
          price: 100,
        },
        {
          name: "Book 3",
          price: 50,
        },
        {
          name: "Book 4",
          price: 10,
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  computed: {
    rows() {
      return this.items.length
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.get_items()

  }
})
```

```html
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.21.2/dist/bootstrap-vue.css" />

<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.12/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.22.0/dist/bootstrap-vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <b-container fluid="xl">
    <div class="api-list">
      <h2>API Listing</h2>

      <b-pagination v-model="currentPage" :total-rows="rows" :per-page="perPage" aria-controls="my-table"></b-pagination>

      <p class="mt-3">Current Page: {{ currentPage }}</p>

      <b-table id="my-table" striped hover :items="items" :per-page="perPage" :current-page="currentPage" small></b-table>
    </div>
  </b-container>
</div>
```